# Is it possible / How to use racket in C++ Applications?

Tags: c++, lisp, racket

I heard that Racket could be embedded (maybe also with C++).

- http://docs.racket-lang.org/inside/index.html
- http://docs.racket-lang.org/foreign/index.html

But I can't find the direct way (example maybe) how to run Racket from C++.

What's a simple example of this?

Comment: For problems with embedding Racket, your best bet is to ask on the [mailing list](http://lists.racket-lang.org/), it's just that it can be difficult to do, and none of the experts in that area are around here...

Comment: If you don't need anything specific from Racket, you could look at
[Guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) another Scheme.

Comment: @Daimrod but is it much easier to do it with guile?

Comment: @nCdy: I believe so, it has been designed with this goal. I've never use it, but [here is](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Programming-in-C.html#Programming-in-C) an example of interfacing Guile with C, it shouldn't be to difficult to do it in C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first manual you mentioned in your question contains a description of the most important steps, together with some examples, in the section "Embedding Racket into a Program" of chapter "1 Overview":

http://docs.racket-lang.org/inside/overview.html#(part._embedding)